# Is There IP Address File Resolver Plugin For Firefox And Chrome?

Tags: internet, ip, resolution, media

Let me explain. When i right click on image, i see its size and other properties, however i would also want to see on which host it is located. It would be nice to have such plugin for Firefox and Chrome that would not only show **IP of server** file resides but also **hosting company server** it is on.

Preferrably it would be nice not only for images but any other media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on an image in firefox and select *View Image Info* you'll get details about the image. Under *Location*, you'll see a URL, take the domain and tld and pop it into
[Whois for Firefox](http://vitzo.com/en/article/whois-lookup-add-on-for-firefox) and it will tell you many details about the domain (including hosting company).

[Hostlogr](http://www.hostlogr.com/) will tell you the hosting information for whatever page you are on in firefox.

[Wipmania](http://www.wipmania.com/plugins/) will give you details like DNS entries (host command in unix), traceroute and ping options and country location for the server.